# Plotly (r) show all hoverinfos of a line on click

Tags: javascript, r, plotly

I have a line-plot with very little data. A bit like this:

```
plot_ly(x = c( -2, 0, 1.5 ),y = c( -2, 1, 2.2), 
        type = 'scatter' ,mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 
 add_trace(x=c(-1,0.4,2.5),y=c(2, 0, -1),type='scatter',mode='lines+markers')
```

I want to know whether `plotly` can display all the hoverinfos of a line at ones. Such that for example when I click on "trace 1" in the legend, I can see it has the points (-1,2), (0.4,0), (2.5,-1) beside the corresponding point. Couldn't find anything so far.

Comment: In the linked post I solved this question using a shiny checkbox. Here I am still searching for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger hover events with `Plotly.Fx` and add the necessary Javascript code by using `htmlwidgets`.

`Fx.hover` needs a `curveNumber` and `curvePoint` (the *n*-th of your trace) as input parameters. If you want to trigger events for multiple points, you need to pass an array of objects.

[image]

```
library("plotly")
library("htmlwidgets")

p <- plot_ly(x = c(-2, 0, 1.5 ),
             y = c(-2, 1, 2.2), 
             type = 'scatter',
             mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 
  add_trace(x = c(-1, 0.4, 2.5),
            y = c(2, 0, -1),
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 
  layout(hovermode = 'closest')

javascript <- "
var myPlot = document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0];
myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data) {
  var hover = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.points[0].data.x.length; i += 1) {
    hover.push({curveNumber: data.points[0].curveNumber,
                pointNumber: i});
  }
  Plotly.Fx.hover(myPlot, hover);
});"
p <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(p, onStaticRenderComplete(javascript), data = list(''))
p
```

---

Note: `Plotly.Fx` will be [deprecated](https://community.plot.ly/t/what-is-plotly-fx/831).

Comment: Basically we have wait for the next plotly release to find out whether this functionality will be preserved. I will still accept your answer, since likely with the current release (1.3.0 for plotly.js and 4.7.1 for the R-package) there won't be any other solution. I hope some user will comment when the new release is out.