# shiny plot comes in two windows (plot does not appear)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I solved my [own question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199423/plotly-r-show-all-hoverinfos-of-a-line-on-click). However my code has a massive flaw: When I run the app, *Shiny only shows me the checkbox*. In R-Studio it shows me the checkbox in a popup-window and the plot in the R-Studio-Viewer tab.

I tried put the two elements in a `sidebarLayout`-Panel. But to no avail. Is there any way to make this work?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput("Addtext", 'lines',c('trace 0','trace 1'),''),width = 2),
    mainPanel(plotOutput('plot1'),width=9)
    )
    ),
  server = function(input, output) {    

      output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      p<-plot_ly(x = c( -2, 0, 1.5 ),y = c( -2, 1, 2.2), type = 'scatter' ,mode = 'lines') %>% 
        add_trace(x=c(-1,0.4,2.5),y=c(2, 0, -1),type='scatter',mode='lines')
      if(!is.null(input$Addtext)){
        if('trace 0'%in%input$Addtext){
          p<- p %>% add_trace(x=c( -2, 0, 1.5 ),y= c( -2, 1, 2.2),type='scatter',mode='text',
                              text=c('(-2,-2)','(0,1)','(1.5,2.2)'),
                              textposition='right',textfont = list(color = '#000000', size = 10),
                              hoverinfo='skip',showlegend=FALSE)    
        }
        if('trace 1'%in%input$Addtext){
          p<- p %>% add_trace(x=c( -1, 0.4, 2.5 ),y= c( 2, 0, -1),type='scatter',mode='text',
                              text=c('(-1,2)','(0.4,0)','(2.5,-1)'),
                              textposition='right',textfont = list(color = '#000000', size = 10),
                              hoverinfo='skip',showlegend=FALSE)
          }
      }
      p
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `plotlyOutput` and `renderPlotly` when using `plotly` package

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput("Addtext", 'lines',c('trace 0','trace 1'),''),width = 2),
    mainPanel(plotlyOutput('plot1'),width=9)
  )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$plot1 = renderPlotly({
      p<-plot_ly(x = c( -2, 0, 1.5 ),y = c( -2, 1, 2.2), type = 'scatter' ,mode = 'lines') %>% 
        add_trace(x=c(-1,0.4,2.5),y=c(2, 0, -1),type='scatter',mode='lines')
      if(!is.null(input$Addtext)){
        if('trace 0' %in% input$Addtext){
          p<- p %>% add_trace(x=c( -2, 0, 1.5 ),y= c( -2, 1, 2.2),type='scatter',mode='text',
                              text=c('(-2,-2)','(0,1)','(1.5,2.2)'),
                              textposition='right',textfont = list(color = '#000000', size = 10),
                              hoverinfo='skip',showlegend=FALSE)    
        }
        if('trace 1' %in% input$Addtext){
          p<- p %>% add_trace(x=c( -1, 0.4, 2.5 ),y= c( 2, 0, -1),type='scatter',mode='text',
                              text=c('(-1,2)','(0.4,0)','(2.5,-1)'),
                              textposition='right',textfont = list(color = '#000000', size = 10),
                              hoverinfo='skip',showlegend=FALSE)
        }
      }
      return(p)
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. Somehow I wasnt sure whether `renderPlotly` is still supported. Guess not everything is on the shiny-cheatsheet.

Comment: `plotly` and most of other `JS` libraries are not supported by `shiny` team so you just have to read the docs https://plot.ly/r/shiny-tutorial/

Comment: realised you made an error in the if function, the strings (e.g. `'trace 0'`) need to come first. Only then comes `input$Addtext`. Otherwise both annotations can't be displayed